# Extracting the trees (predictor) from random forest classifier

Tags: scikit-learn

I have a specific technical question about sklearn, random forest classifier.

After fitting the data with the ".fit(X,y)" method, 
is there a way to extract the actual trees
from the estimator object, in some common format, so the ".predict(X)" 
method can be implemented outside python?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes, the trees of a forest are stored in the `estimators_` attribute of
the forest object.

You can have a look at the implementation of the `export_graphviz`
function to learn out to write your custom exporter:

https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/main/sklearn/tree/_export.py

Here is the usage doc for this function:

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/tree.html#classification

Comment: Not yet (as of 0.14.1). There is a pull request here: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/pull/2530

Comment: Is there any example for the solution been tried, As I tried in Google Colab I got error , ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-131ec55b94e7> in <module>()
     19 import numpy as np
     20 
---> 21 from ..utils.validation import check_is_fitted
     22 
     23 from . import _criterion

ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is and @ogrisel answer enabled me to implement the following snippet, which enables to use a (partially trained) random forest to predict the values. It saves a lot of time if you want to cross validate a random forest model over the number of trees:

```
rf_model = RandomForestRegressor()
rf_model.fit(x, y)

estimators = rf_model.estimators_

def predict(w, i):
    rf_model.estimators_ = estimators[0:i]
    return rf_model.predict(x)
```

I explained this in more details here : [extract trees from a Random Forest](https://www.thekerneltrip.com/python/extract-trees-random-forest/)